# Why is my tissue sample coagulating during centrifugation? How can I prevent this?

Tags: lab-techniques, centrifugation

I am working on extracting water-soluble compounds from a biological tissue sample. A problem I am encountering is that the sample is too cloudy with debris/large tissue pieces to filter into HPLC vials for analysis. So my hypothesized solution is to centrifuge the samples and try filtering the supernatant instead.

When I tried this (centrifuging 5mL at 12000rpm for 5 minutes) the resulting sample was gelatinized/coagulated and even more resistant to filtration. Any ideas on why this is happening, centrifugation parameters to try instead?

Comment: What tissue are you working with, and how are you prepping it? If coagulation is an issue, adding heparin into your sample preparation procedure should inhibit it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for information on what makes a good question and answers. To answer your question, as @MattDMo asked, we would need specifics on the tissue, reagents and procedures you are using in your preparation.  Also, besides centrifugation, what else have you attempted and how do others in your lab overcome this problem?

Comment: Your question and self-answer don't seem to make sense. You write about "platelet" in the question, but then say you were using plant-based samples in you answer. There is no point in posting publicly unless you are clear enough that someone else can learn from what you've posted. Consequently, I've voted to close this as "Needs details or clarity". Please follow the above advice and then either [edit] or delete these posts according to what you've learned (and whether you are willing to put the work in to improve your posts).

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question: I was using plant-based food samples that were extracted at medium/low temperatures. This denatured the proteins into absorbing more water. The samples were also starch-containing and gelatinized during centrifugation. I am only unsure why centrifuging initiates starch gelatinization like when cooking.